# Convert dataframe to list of record WITHOUT brackets

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
d = { "letter": ["a", "b", "c"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

[image]

if I use `df.values.tolist()`  , I will get

[image]

BUT my expected result is below

```
letter =['a','b','c']
```

which without the brackets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the `to_list()` function after indexing the column of interest:

```
import pandas as pd
d = { "letter": ["a", "b", "c"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

# Call to_list() in column of interest
letter = df.letter.to_list()
```

`letter` variable now holds:

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
d = { "letter": ["a", "b", "c"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

df["letter"].values.tolist()
```

Output:

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
d = { "letter": ["a", "b", "c"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

df.values.ravel().tolist()

['a', 'b', 'c']
```

if you print below then it'll be clear

```
print(df.values)

array([['a'],
   ['b'],
   ['c']], dtype=object)
```